# Need to Kill Batch File

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

Ok, I've searched many sites for an answer for a few days now. If there is an answer somewhere, if you point me there is fine. I am trying to get batch file "A" to read text file "B" and take some information and replace code in batch file "C". On first run it will do this and then run batch file "C". While batch file "C" is running, I have batch file "A" watching text file "B" for change in the last modified part of the file. When change is detected, I need batch file "C" to stop, Read/Write Text file "B" to Batch file "C" then start batch file "C" again.

I have the code working to do everything except when I run the Batch file "A" every time change is detected, it starts a new batch file run of "C".

to start batch file "C" I use:

```
import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen(r'start cmd /c C:\Users\james\Documents\FollowMeMap.bat', shell=True)
```

I've tried to use p.terminate() and p.kill() but neither works. Thanks for any help everyone has.

Comment: You're running `cmd /c "start cmd /c C:\Users\james\Documents\FollowMeMap.bat"`, because of `shell=True`.  Why don't you simply run the batch file without `shell=True`? If you need a new console window, then use `p = subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Users\james\Documents\FollowMeMap.bat', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`. Like this, process `p` is the actual cmd.exe instance that's executing "FollowMeMap.bat", and you can `p.kill()` it.

Answer (score 1):

On windows I use that and it works fine. Can also be done by directly calling win32 api.

```
 os.system ("taskkill /F /PID "+str (p.pid))
```

P being your subprocess popen object.

Edit: that is not working probably because of `start` prefix. You need to create a python thread and run Popen on the real command. Here's a working example.

I have created a class so no need for global variables (I hate them). It creates a thread that once started through `start()` performs the `Popen`. It runs an executable so no need for `shell=True`, but for a .bat file you probably need it.
It stores the p object in a private `__pipe` attribute and waits.

The `doit` method, after having started the thread, waits 5 seconds, then kills the pipe using the command you tried.

The difference with your tries is that it does not need the windows `start` command, but uses python to run in background, so it has better control on the process (`start` just fires up the process and stops, you have no information on the process)

Tested with Python 3.4

```
import threading
import subprocess
import time

class Runner():
    def run_command(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe")
        self.__pipe = p
        p.wait()

    def doit(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run_command)
        t.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.__pipe.terminate()

r = Runner()
r.doit()
```

Comment: I inserted your code and it doesn't seem to do anything, Since I am kinda new to python, was there something I was suppose to change before running the batch file? Note: my subprocess.popen is p= in my file